# Mule4 Bulk insert after map in dataweave prompting an error for field contains multiple object

Tags: java, bulkinsert, dataweave, mule4

I am trying to insert bulk data to mssql after batch processing.

Below is the input to bulk insert component in Mule4:

`[
  {
    "schemaId": 311,
    "createDT": "2019-04-29 04:22:51.535",
    "jsonData": {
      "Employee Name": "Becky Forgey"
    }
  },
  {
    "schemaId": 311,
    "createDT": "2019-04-29 04:22:51.536",
    "jsonData": {
      "Employee Name": "sahana"
    }
  }
]`

Database Query is:

```
INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[EmployeeData] (SchemaID,CreateDatetime,JsonData) VALUES (:schemaId,:createDT,:jsonData)
```

INPUT parameter is payload.

If i send a string value for jsonData it is inserting but batch result consists of multiple records and i am mapping it in dataweave.

Getting below error if i try to insert above json:

```
Message               : The conversion from UNKNOWN to NVARCHAR is unsupported.
Error type            : DB:QUERY_EXECUTION
Element               : test-mapFlow/processors/5 @ test-map:test-map.xml:41 (Bulk insert)
Element XML           : <db:bulk-insert doc:name="Bulk insert" doc:id="98f8b9a0-b3d2-4beb-a31c-9f76af7f1447" config-ref="Database_Config">
<db:sql>INSERT INTO [rq].[dbo].[EmployeeMasterData] (SchemaID,CreateDatetime,JsonData) VALUES (:schemaId,:createDT,:jsonData)</db:sql>
</db:bulk-insert>
```

Please guide

Answer (score 0):

Please, provide full script how you present data for the SQL. Usually it has mapping between your values and sql values. Without it I can only guess and my guess is that instead of jsonData ir should be jsonData."Employee Name"

Another guess - I cannot confirm it without proper logging - jsonData is absent. To avoid such issues defualt value should be provided for each parameter.

In general - try to avoid muitple conversions or do them on one platform as close to end as possible https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/AvoidCoversionsOrMakeThemNative.html